# Is there any shortcut in SAS to interpret Limited Probability Model coefficients?

Tags: statistics, sas

By LPM I mean that the dependent variable is polychotomous (e.g. 1,2,3 4) and (NOT binary 1 or 0).
I know how to transform the coefficients manually by reverse calculating the `PDF`. Is there any command in `SAS` that would do it automatically?

If I start lets say

```
proc logistic
OR    
proc probit
```

I want to explain what happens if the independent variable changes by 1 unit?

Comment: [http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/dae/probit.htm](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/dae/probit.htm)

Comment: Sounds like a question for [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely sure, but i believe you are looking for something like PROC MDC.